# Celery hangs with 100% CPU usage

Tags: python, celery, python-3.4

I am running Celery with Amazon SQS. In celery task, task is sending put request to a server using Python `requests` library of.

After successfully running the task for the first request, Celery hangs with 100% CPU usage.

I am using Celery 4.0.2 and Kombu 4.0.0

The Strace Dump for the hanging pid is -->>

```
futex(0x999104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x999100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x999140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x999104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x999100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x999140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x999104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x999100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x999140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x999104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x999100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x999140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x999104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x999100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x999140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x999104, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x999100, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x999140, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
```

Comment: I don't think its an issue here.
Can you post the task code?